# Apache nifi concurrent task

Tags: java, concurrency, apache-nifi, java.util.concurrent

How Nifi uses concurrency framework to achieve parallelism.

[nifi concurrent task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9AS5.jpg)

If I assign concurrent task to 5.
At a time five flowfile will be processed by nifi processor,then onTrigger is called from each task.

I created a custom processor which extends AbstractProcessor, but I don't have a idea which method will be called to process the flowfile concurrently.

Provide a brief explanation how custom processor achieve concurrent tasks.

Answer (score 0):

By default all flowfiles processed in concurrent mode unless you limit it when configuring flow:

[image]

Also you could specify if processor should be scheduled on all nodes in cluster or only on primary one.

[image]

And finally there is a total limit of threads in nifi per node in cluster

`Sandwich menu -> Controller Settings -> General -> Maximum timer driven thread count`

[image]

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#Controller_Services